# Android App gets stuck on splashscreen when launched on physical device but works fine when on an emulator

Tags: android

When I run the app on my physical device (huawei.Android version 4.4.2),it launches well but hangs on the splash screen.When I use the emulator(Nexus 5 API 24) ,it launches the splash screen then goes to the login activity screen.What could be the problem?

My splash Activity

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 GPSTracker gpsTracker;
    protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
    boolean permission=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        getDeviceToken();
        getpermission();
        gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this, this);
        permission= SharedPreferenceWriter.getInstance(this).getBoolean(SharedPreferenceKey.permission_granted_location,false);

        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean statusOfGPS = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (statusOfGPS) {
            if (permission) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (SharedPreferenceWriter.getInstance(SplashActivity.this).getBoolean(SharedPreferenceKey.currentLogin, false)) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, Login.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                }, 2000);

            } //else
                //Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,"permission not granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else
            new StartLocationAlert(SplashActivity.this);


    }

    private void getpermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissionforApp();
        }

    }

    private void requestPermissionforApp() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Current Location needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 123);
        }


    }

    private void getDeviceToken() {

        final Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.e(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>", "thred IS  running");
                SharedPreferenceWriter mPreference = SharedPreferenceWriter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    if (mPreference.getString(SharedPreferenceKey.device_token).isEmpty()) {
                        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
//                        String token = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
//                                android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                        Log.e("Generated Device Token", "-->" + token);
                        if (token == null) {
                            getDeviceToken();
                        } else {
                            mPreference.writeStringValue(SharedPreferenceKey.device_token, token);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                super.run();
            }
        };
        thread.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        try {
            if (requestCode == 123) {
                int lenght = grantResults.length;

                for (int grantlength = 0; grantlength < grantResults.length; grantlength++) {
                    if (grantResults[grantlength] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        getDeviceToken();
                        SharedPreferenceWriter.getInstance(this).writeBooleanValue(SharedPreferenceKey.permission_granted_location, true);
                        gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this, SplashActivity.this);
                        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, Login.class));
                        finish();
                    } else if (grantResults[grantlength] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        boolean b = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permissions[grantlength]);
                        if (!b) {
                            requestPermissionforApp();
                        } else {
                            requestPermissionforApp();
                        }
                    } else {
                        requestPermissionforApp();
                    }
                }

            } else {
                requestPermissionforApp();
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK: {
                        // showDialog();
                        //new SplashActivity();
                        //gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this, SplashActivity.this);
                        if (SharedPreferenceWriter.getInstance(SplashActivity.this).getBoolean(SharedPreferenceKey.currentLogin,false))
                        {
                            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }else {
                            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, Login.class));
                            finish();
                        }

                        // All required changes were successfully made
                        break;
                    }
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED: {
                        new StartLocationAlert(SplashActivity.this);
                        // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                        break;
                    }
                    default: {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

My Manifest file:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
  <uses-feature
      android:name="android.hardware.camera"
      android:required="true"/>

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:largeHeap="true"
      android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_logo"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
      >

    <activity
        android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/TranparentToolbar">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.SignUp"
        android:theme="@style/TranparentToolbar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.Otp"
        android:theme="@style/TranparentToolbar"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.MapDrawerActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.Description"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.FoodMenu"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.MyKart"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.UserAddress"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.PaymentMode"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.FacebookLogin"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.GoogleLogin"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.MapForPayment"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.Login"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.CreditCard"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.PaymentBackground"
        android:theme="@style/TranparentToolbar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"/>
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id"/>

    <!-- <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
         android:value="@string/release_key" />-->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/release_key"/>


    <activity
        android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.SearchMap"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_map"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.Settings"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.WebviewActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.ChangePassword"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.ContactUs"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.Notification"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.MyFav"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.MapForOrderDispatch"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.MapRouteAct"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.TakeImage"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.sats.quickeats.util.TakePhoto"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.ForgotPass"
        android:theme="@style/TranparentToolbar"/>
    <activity android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.SearchFilter"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.ResetPass"
        android:theme="@style/TranparentToolbar"/>

    <service android:name="com.sats.quickeats.fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.sats.quickeats.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="44b5915daf7330d0de425de1d6bc82af9e2d242a"/>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.sats.quickeats.activities.DeliveryBoytStatus"
        android:process=":remote"/>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.sats.quickeats.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>

    <!--<provider-->
    <!--android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"-->
    <!--android:authorities="com.mobulous.restaurantapp.fileprovider"-->
    <!--android:exported="false"-->
    <!--android:grantUriPermissions="true"-->
    <!--tools:replace="android:authorities">-->
    <!--<meta-data-->
    <!--android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"-->
    <!--android:resource="@xml/file_paths"-->
    <!--tools:replace="android:resource"/>-->
    <!--</provider>-->

    <!--android:name="com.sats.quickeats.util.RestroApplication"-->


  </application>


</manifest>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't enabled GPS in the settings,

```
boolean statusOfGPS = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

This will return `false`, when gps is not turned on, and you will be stuck in your splash screen activity because of `if(statusOfGPS)`. Turn on your GPS on the device and you are good to go. Make your you have required permissions in your `manifest` file.

You can also use `manager.isLocationEnabled()` to check the current status of location.

Comment: and @muminers . I changed `permission= SharedPreferenceWriter.getInstance(this).getBoolean(SharedPreferenceKey.permission_granted_location,false);` from **false** to **true**  and it works.Thanks for your help